# count 2 fields combined in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I have two fields in my Qlikview Data - Procedures and 2nd Element

They both contain data that is duplicated between them;

eg Procedures field has: "This", "That", "The other" whilst 2nd Element Field has: "This", "That", "Something else"

I want to create a bar chart that can show the combined totals of the two fields:

eg "This" = 2, "That" = 2, "The other" = 1, "something else" = 1

No matter what expression i put in though i can't get it to work properly.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to solve this using a script approach. You'll need :

- Make sure that every row in you table has an unique id (for instance using RowNo() as RecordId in the Load statement)
- After loading the table (let's call it DataTable), do a first resident Load like this LOAD RecordId, Procedures as NewColumn resident DataTable.
- Do the same thing for the second column : LOAD RecordId, 2ndElement as NewColumn resident DataTable.

You'll end up with a new table that combines both columns in one. On the chart you'll need to use NewColumn as the dimension and Count(RecordId) as the expression.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
Data:
LOAD * INLINE [
    F1, F2
    This, This
    That,     That
    The Other,     Something else
];

load F1 as Dim Resident Data;
join
Load F2 as Dim Resident Data ;
```

then use Dim as a Dimension and in the expresion write:

```
count(if(Dim=F1,F1)) +
count(if(Dim=F2,F2))
```